# Wide landscape tabular doesn't fit. The tabular is cut off at the sides

Tags: tables, landscape

So I'm making this table for my thesis but it didn't fit. After making it use landscape it still cuts off at the sides. Is there some way I can let it continue on another page or make this fit?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| l| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!25}
        Component & Methode   & Periode & Voorbehandeling  & Staalextractie/staalreactie & Staalopzuivering  & Analyse  & Bron gedetailleerde methode-omschrijving\\ \hline
        
        \cellcolor{gray!80}{PCBs} & PCBbio001 & 2010-2015 (sem 1) &/ &Bligh and dyer methode 
        (methanol/chloroform) &Opzuivering met Silica en Alox &GC-ECD &~\citep{Tabel2}\\ \hline
        
        & PCBbio002 &2015 (sem 2) – 2020 (sem 1) &/ &Smedes extractie (cyclohexaan) &Opzuivering met Silica en Alox &GC-ECD &~\citep{Tabel2,Tabel3}\\\hline

        & PCBbio003a & 2020 (sem 2) - heden &Vriesdrogen &PLE (versnelde vloeistofextractie) (hexaan/aceton) &Florisil + Opzuivering met Silica en Alox &GC-MS &Niet gepubliceerd, methode combineert opwerking volgens ~\citep{Tabel3} voor PAKs met analyse van PCBs in sediment zoals beschreven in ~\citep{publicatieDavid}\\\hline

        \cellcolor{gray!80}{PAKs} &PAHbio001 & 2010-2011 &/ &Verzeping (KOH/MeOH) &LLE met hexaan + Alox &LC-fluorescentie &~\citep{Tabel4}\\\hline

        & PAHbio002 &2012 (sem1) &/ &Verzeping (KOH/MeOH) &LLE met hexaan + Alox &GC-MS &Niet gepubliceerd, methode combineert opwerkingen volgens ~\citep{Tabel4} met analyse volgens ~\citep{Tabel3} \\\hline
        
        & PAHbio003 &2012 (sem2 2) - heden &Vriesdrogen &PLE (versnelde vloeistofextractie) (hexaan/aceton) &Florisil + Opzuivering met Silica en Alox &GC-MS &~\citep{Tabel3}\\\hline

        \cellcolor{gray!80}{Metalen (Hg)} &ZMbio001 & 2010-heden &/ &Droge verbranding met O2 &Goudadsorptie &AAS &~\citep{Tabel1}\\\hline 

        \cellcolor{gray!80}{Metalen (Overige)} &ZMbio002 &2010-heden &/ &Microgolfovendestructie met HNO3 &/ &ICP-MS &~\citep{Tabel1}\\\hline 

        \cellcolor{gray!80}{Vetgehalte} &TOTLIPbio001 &2010-2015 (sem1) &/ &Bligh and dyer methode (methanol/chloroform) &/ &Gravimetrisch &~\citep{Tabel2}\\\hline 

        & TOTLIPbio002 &2015 (sem 2) - heden &/ &Smedes extractie (cyclohexaan) &/ &Gravimetrisch &~\citep{Tabel3}\\\hline

        \cellcolor{gray!80}{Droge stof} &DSbio001 &2010-2013 (sem 1) &/ &Ovendrogen met zeezand bij 105°C &/ &Gravimetrisch &Niet gepubliceerd\\\hline 

        & DSbio002 &2013 (sem 2) - heden &/ &Vriesdrogen &/ &Gravimetrisch &Niet gepubliceerd\\\hline
       
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Note that it does not make sense to wrap `landscape` around a float. Additionally please extend your example to a full but minimal document. Then others can easily copy and test your code.

Comment: Note that there isn't much we can do when you try to cram that much data into one table. You should probably redesign your table or show the data some other way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe get some inspirations for options to make a table better fit the given space from [here ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/47927)